# Name of unknown effect where liquid moves when placed on a jagged surface

Tags: classical-mechanics

I recently saw a [video](http://uk.reuters.com/video/2013/11/29/physics-students-a-maze-with-leidenfrost?videoId=274738341) in which a water droplet, when dropped on a jagged surface (see photo), and whilst under the [Leidenfrost Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect), moved. Does anyone know the name of this effect?

[image: Water droplet on a jagged surface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From browsing a few related abstracts, there doesn't seem to be an established name for the phenomenon. The jagged surface, however, is called a "ratchet".

The abstract of the original paper {1} refers to it as a "pumping effect", but this seems more like a description than a name. There's a Nature Physics paper on the subject {2}, but again the abstract doesn't use any specific term for the phenomenon. There is one other abstract I found {3}, which calls the phenomenon the "Leidenfrost ratchet". This was my first guess, and it's what I typed into Google to find these papers.

**References** (with apologies for inconsistent formatting)

{1} Self-Propelled Leidenfrost Droplets. Phys. Rev. Lett. 96, 154502 – Published 19 April 2006. H. Linke, B. J. Alemán, L. D. Melling, M. J. Taormina, M. J. Francis, C. C. Dow-Hygelund, V. Narayanan, R. P. Taylor, and A. Stout. http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.96.154502

{2} Leidenfrost on a ratchet. Guillaume Lagubeau,    Marie Le Merrer,    Christophe Clanet   & David Quéré.
Nature Physics 7, 395–398 (2011) doi:10.1038/nphys1925. Published 20 February 2011. http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v7/n5/full/nphys1925.html

{3} Leidenfrost Gas Ratchets Driven by Thermal Creep. Phys. Rev. Lett. 107, 164502 – Published 13 October 2011. Alois Würger. http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.164502